# Dual booting ubuntu and windows, window won't load even after updating with <sudo update-grub>

Tags: dual-boot, windows

Windows won't boot after installing Ubuntu from a usb stick. I tried updating grub:

```
$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

It did't help.I checked my partitions and there is a microsoft reserved partition at /dev/sda3 and flags msftres.

I also tried updating grub from startup up window from advanced options under ubuntu header.

While installing i made three separate partitions, and before anything I had my window partition shrunk, as was required.

Comment: thank you , it was useful to some degree , i have now windows(uefi) option on boot screen, but it still won't load  and goes through diagnosing pc to attempting to repair.....i am trying to repair window boot loader, useful link  @karel

Comment: How did you get Windows UEFI back on the boot screen? Was it with Rescatux? The reason why I'm asking is that Rescatux has several UEFI options in the **boot options** section.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/217970/829598 this helped. I didn't used Rescatux, I still have to make it work though.  How do I know if didn't wiped my windows drive() out during installation.@karel

Comment: Thanks for telling me which answer helped you so that I could upvote it. The command `sudo fdisk -l` lists all the partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Does grub bootloader work fine? If so you can just choose to boot to **Windows** from grub menu. Otherwise will you please post more information in this?

Comment: if you follow previous comment , I have got Windows8(UEFI) option back on grub menu, but it is still not loading...just says attempting repairs, I guess I have to use boot repair disk as suggested on quora  http://qr.ae/TUTo9m  @AshishKafle